# can't trigger focus on a textbox in angular and ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to set focus on a textbox through an onclick trigger and it doesn't seem to work in my ionic angular implementation.  It works if I take it out of angluar and ionic

Here's the template

```
<ion-view title="Create">
  <ion-content class="has-header">
     <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="focus here" id="test" />
        <button ng-click="test()">TEST</button>
      </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And the js

```
$scope.test = function(){
    document.getElementById('test').focus();
  };
```

Comment: Can you set up a plunker?

Comment: doesn't work in an ionic build so the plunker example would actually work correctly

Comment: Well i tried your code in an ionic plunker and it works without any issues.. Check your console for any errors.

Comment: it works fine in plunker, it only doesn't work in ionic - it shows no errors in console.

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey Have you find anything on this ?

Comment: put your "document.getElementById('test').focus();" in a $timeout function. with at least 200ms delay. Should work.

Answer (score 11):

I found out the answer from the forum:
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/focus-method-doesnt-work-on-input-textarea-etc/5606/14

Turns out you need to add the Ionic Keyboard plugin and add these preferences in the config.xml:

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />

<feature name="Keyboard">
  <param name="ios-package" value="IonicKeyboard" onload="true" />
</feature>
```

After that, the focus() function will work.

Comment: <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" /> this line helped me

Answer (score 6):

Easiest and quickest way for me to accomplish this was as follows:

```
$scope.test = function(){
    $timeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('test').select();
    }, 0);
};
```

Comment: Please, don't forget to read @IndraAdam's answer about `<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />` or if will not work for iOS devices